# Change external app window from tool to overlapped

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using Unity to build games. It has a main window and dockable windows. I have several screens. I undock some windows to other screens, however I'm also using other apps, and when I come back to the main Unity window, I don't want the child windows to go in front of my other app windows.

Using Spy++, I saw that the child windows have `WS_POPUP` and `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` styles, so I did this:

```
EnumWindows(FindUnityWindows, NULL);
```

And:

```
BOOL CALLBACK FindUnityWindows(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char class_name[80];

    GetClassName(hwnd, class_name, sizeof(class_name));
    int processid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL);


    if (!strcmp(class_name, "UnityContainerWndClass"))
    {
        long style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
        style |= WS_OVERLAPPED;
        style &= ~(WS_POPUP);

        long exstyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        exstyle |= WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        exstyle &= ~(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);

        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle);
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Which effectively changes the styles (I checked in Spy++), but the windows behaviour doesn't change. I don't have a tab in the taskbar, and the windows still appears when I activate the main window.

What more can I do?

Comment: Those aren't child windows. They are owned windows. Owned windows are always displayed in front of their respective owner window. That's built into the system, and you cannot change that.

Comment: ohh... maybe a hook to cancel activation ?

Comment: Or maybe hooking the CreateWindowEx function to remove parent hwnd should work ?

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of ways in which you can break an application.

Comment: You may use [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) to *Change the parent window of the specified child window*. See [Relationship to Parent Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#relationship-to-parent-window).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Yes but the problem is with owner window as IInspectable noticed, and it can't be changed.